# HTTP Request in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms App for Android and iOS which is supposed to consume an API. The API is kind of built in a REST spirit, I'm hosting the API on a local IIS Express server and my Android emulator has no problem finding it (tested on various endpoints and I can also display the api-doc).
I'm trying to get in touch with a `http://IPOfMyComputer/api/Stuffs` endpoint which gives me a JSON list of Stuff. Using Postman I successfully get all the stuff I needed, a valid auth token in that case, to build a proper HTTP GET request. I'm using the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package to build this request as it seemed to be the proper tool to do the job. I'm doing this request building process in Xamarin.Forms "Main" project (not the iOS or Android one, the other one which I don't know how to name which is automatically by Visual Studio).

My code looks like this:

```
var rootUri = "http://IPOfMyComputer"
var requestedUri = "/api/Stuffs"
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", 
"blablabla");
var response = await client.GetAsync(rootUri + requestedUri);
```

And this gives me an error "NotSupportedException" on the last instruction.
I'm clueless here so some help would be really appreciated.
**Edit**
The proper error message is 
"System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: Any further error details? Does the exception say anything else?

Comment: What exactly not supported? Do you have inner exceptions?

Comment: Hello, I'm back on my workstation and here is the error message I get from VS: 
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of that error:
Turns out it wasn't directly linked with the `GetAsync` method but with some mess in the code related with async/await use.
There was a bunch of crappy code everywhere. I dropped it all to go back to a regular MVVM logic and I put the async/await logic into methods invoked by eventhandlers (instead of trying to "create" an async builder for a class...).